# Getting variable from Database

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to get `payment_transaction_id` but it doesn't work. Same code works to get info from users, I didn't understand why couldn't get the data.

This is how table created(which is working and has data in it already).

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
    $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'iyzico_order_refunds';
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name2 (
        iyzico_order_refunds_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        order_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
        item_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
        payment_transaction_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
        paid_price VARCHAR(50),
        total_refunded VARCHAR(50),
        PRIMARY KEY  (iyzico_order_refunds_id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    dbDelta($sql);
```

And I am trying to pull transaction ID with this:

```
$payment_transaction_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT payment_transaction_id FROM $wpdb->iyzico_order_refunds WHERE order_id=769 AND item_id=760" );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to use `{$wpdb->prefix}iyzico_order_refunds` instead of `$wpdb->iyzico_order_refunds`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend the table prefix to `iyzico_order_refunds` instead of the `$wpdb` object:

```
$payment_transaction_id = $wpdb->get_var( 
    "SELECT payment_transaction_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}iyzico_order_refunds} WHERE order_id=769 AND item_id=760"
);
```